# How to convert an integer to short in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I have on my server side (c#) an integer `a`:

```
int a = 65512;
```

and when I can cast it to short : `(short)a` is equal to -24

I want to move on this conversion to the client side (javascript)

I tried to convert it to first to binary : `a.toString(2)` and then do an `a.toString(2) & 0xFF` but in vain

How can I cast a number to a short one on javascript side ?

Comment: In JavaScript, there is no such thing as "casting". Also I'm not sure what you expected to happen when using binary and `&` on a string and an integer.

Comment: Yes there's no specific types in javascript, i mean not available for you to define, that's the compiler job, hence the 'var' keyword, don't confuse it with the C# var keyword.

Comment: the desired output is -24 , i know there is no such type on javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have `int` and `short` and such, it has `number`, which is an IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point type (and typed arrays as in [Patrick Roberts' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50179301/157247)). However, for certain operations, it acts like it has a 32-bit integer type.

You could take your number and use bit shifting operators to lose half of that 32-bit value, like this:

```js
var a = 65512;
a = (a << 16) >> 16;
console.log(a);
```

Comment: And what's special about typed arrays? They don't use the same 'number' internally?

Comment: @Evk: No, they use the type of the typed array. So an `Int16Array` uses 16-bit ints, a `Float32Array` uses 32-bit floats, etc. (There's `Float64Array`, which is basically of `number`s.) And one of the really cool things about them is that you can have an underlying bit buffer with different views on the bits. More [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays).

Comment: Thanks, I just had such impression (that they use number internally) because there is no Int64Array.

Comment: @Evk that's because they'd be boxed as `Float64` which means that the integer precision wouldn't be preserved, so it wouldn't make sense to have them.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes I understand, but if they do not use usual number type internally, and use some special types, as suggested above - why is it a problem? I mean they could introduce real 64bit int.

Comment: @Evk: It's a problem when you act on them, because they leave the typed array and go into a normal variable, and thus become `number`, and lose integer precision. Brendah Eich did propose an actual 64-bit int type at one point, I don't know why it foundered. But 64-bit int typed arrays are coming via the [BitInt proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint) for arbitrary-precision ints, which has explicit support for 64-bit int typed array handling and can be optimized to native 64-bit math ops by the JS engine.

Answer (score 9):

You can coerce a number in JavaScript to a particular numeric type by making use of [`TypedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray)'s, specifically, [`Int16Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int16Array):

```js
function toShort(number) {
  const int16 = new Int16Array(1)
  int16[0] = number
  return int16[0]
}

console.log(toShort(65512))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to understand that C# is overflowing the number so you can just check it's over the max value for a short which is 32767 (07FFF) and subtract the max value of an int+1 which is 65536 (0x10000). For example:

```js
var number = 65512
var shortValue = number > 0x7FFF ? number - 0x10000 : number;
console.log(shortValue);
```

Comment: Might make it easier to understand if you replace `65536` and `32767` with `0x10000` and `0x7FFF` respectively, if you're using magic numbers.

Comment: 0xFFFF isn't 655536 :)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not support variable types such as short.
You'll have to handle ensuring the number is in short on the server side and keep it as a string in the JavaScript side.